# Smart Mirror Project - Touchscreen

Tags: smart-device

What would be the best approach to implementing touchscreen to a smart mirror?

I have not bought the monitor yet but am wondering whether it would be better buying a overlay touchscreen or by using a touchscreen LCD and using a specialist mirror.

As far as my research has concluded the latter is not possible or wouldn't work.

If it would work what specs would need to conformed to make it work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is step by step tutorial with all the materials you will need.

http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-Smart-Mirror/

Comment: I've seen that post before - what I'm asking for is if the glass (or in this case acrylic) would work with a capacitive touchscreen LCD or if I would have to buy a touchscreen overlay to go on top of the mirror.